# no matching constructor for initialization of 'mapped_type' std::map error

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have this a class called 'Card' and I am trying to store some of its objects in a std::map
Card.hpp:

```
class Card
{
public:
    enum ValueType { NOVALUE, ACE };
    enum FaceType { NOFACE, CLUBS };

    Card(const ValueType & _value, const FaceType & _face);
    Card(const Card & _card);
private:
    ValueType m_value;
    FaceType m_face;
};
```

Here is how I store and access it:
Deck.hpp:

```
#include <map>

class Card;

class Deck
{
    public:
        Deck();

        std::size_t length() const;

        Card get_card(const int & _num);

    private:
        std::map<int, Card> m_deck;
};
```

Deck.cpp:

```
#include "Card.hpp"

Deck::Deck()
{
    m_deck.insert(std::pair<int, Card>(0, Card(Card::NOVALUE, Card::NOFACE)));
    m_deck.insert(std::pair<int, Card>(1, Card(Card::ACE, Card::CLUBS)));
}
std::size_t Deck::length() const
{
    return m_deck.size();
}

Card Deck::get_card(const int & _num)
{
    return m_deck[_num];
}
```

Now, when I compile it I get following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:453:45: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'mapped_type' (aka 'Card')
          __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
                                            ^
Deck.cpp:69:18: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::map<int, Card, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Card> > >::operator[]' requested here
    return m_deck[_num];
                 ^
./Card.hpp:30:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
        Card(const ValueType & _value, const FaceType & _face);
        ^
./Card.hpp:32:2: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
        Card(const Card & _card);
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Why am I getting this error? I am using Card only as a value!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that for a map, `m_deck[_num]` is designed to insert a default constructed `Card` if the element isn't already there. And `Card` doesn't have a default constructor.

You can use `map::find` to see if the entry is there, without creating one.

Comment: It only works if the `_num` element is present. Otherwise find will return `m_deck.end()`, which doesn't have a `second`.

Comment: Yeah, but that is closer to expected result than trying to return default objects. At least for me.

Answer (score 0):

For `Deck::get_card()` to compile, `Card` needs to provide a default constructor (presumably initializing the object to `Card::NOVALUE`, `Card::NOFACE`).

The reason for that is that `m_deck[_num]` returns a default-constructed instance of `Card` is `_num` is not in the map.

Comment: A separate question is, does he really need a map here.